# ios capture screenshot, but there is a blank(transparent) on the top, it is the status-bar

Tags: ios, screenshot, statusbar

[image: screenshot, 960*640, but with 44pix transparent status-bar]

screenshot, 960*640, but with 44pix transparent status-bar on the top of the picture.

How to capture a picture with 916pix height? I do not need that blank bar on the top.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)takeScreenShot{
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]){
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0.0f);
    }else{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
    }
    [window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    //
    NSString *documentsDirectory= [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSString *filePath= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SYS_screen_shot@2x.png"];
    //
    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have access to the application frame with this
`[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]`
That will give you the position of your application on the screen

---

`[window.rootViewController.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];`

If what you want is the `root view` of your application, you should take that view to `renderInContext`. I just tested it and it work.